# Docker container automatically exits on release mode .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, I have added Docker support and everything working as expected on debug mode but whenever I change it to release mode (in Visual Studio) as execution option I choose Docker (same as in debug mode), the container automatically closes.

In out tab I'm seeing this message

> The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

`Program.cs`:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Serilog;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business.ServicesImplementations;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core.Abstractions;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions.Repositories;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase.Entities;

namespace WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        // Add services to the container.
        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGameDbContext>(
            optionBuilder => optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Game.Session";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/admin/Auth/Login");

        // Add business services
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IQuestionService, QuestionService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IAnswerService, AnswerService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISourceService, JsonFileSourceService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IGameService, GameService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IPrizeService, PrizeService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IColorPrizeService, PrizeColorService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginUserService, LoginUserService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdvertiseService, AdvertiseService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IClickedAdService, ClickedAdService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IGameTimer, GameTimerService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISocialMediaLinkService, SocialMediaLinkService>();

        // Add repositories
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Question>, Repository<Question>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Answer>, Repository<Answer>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Game>, Repository<Game>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<GameQuestion>, Repository<GameQuestion>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Prize>, Repository<Prize>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<ColorPrize>, Repository<ColorPrize>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<LoginUser>, Repository<LoginUser>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Advertise>, Repository<Advertise>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<ClickedAd>, Repository<ClickedAd>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<GameTimer>, Repository<GameTimer>>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<SocialMediaLink>, Repository<SocialMediaLink>>();

        Log.Information("Start !!!");

        try
        {
            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads")),
                RequestPath = "/uploads"
            });
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMiddleware<PageLoadMiddleware>();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "AdminGame",
                    areaName: "AdminGame",
                    pattern: "admin/{controller=Auth}/{action=Login}/{id?}"
                );

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });

            app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
            errorMessage.Append("The application failed to start. Exception: ");
            errorMessage.Append(ex.Message);
            errorMessage.Append(" StackTrace: ");
            errorMessage.Append(ex.StackTrace);

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                errorMessage.Append(" InnerException: ");
                errorMessage.Append(ex.InnerException.Message);
                errorMessage.Append(" InnerException StackTrace: ");
                errorMessage.Append(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
            }

            Log.Fatal(errorMessage.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    private static string GetPathToLogFile()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
        sb.Append(@"\logs\");
        sb.Append($"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddhhmmss}");
        sb.Append("data.log");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame"
RUN dotnet build "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.dll"]
```

Comment: Do you supply an appsettings.json file to the application, either baked into the image or volumed in?

Comment: Yes I put it to image .but not as volume

Answer (score 0):

It worked afer changing the sequnce of lines in Program.cs and added folder to docker file and give permission to this folder .

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the ASP.NET Core runtime image as the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
# Create uploads directory and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app/uploads
RUN chmod -R 777 /app/uploads
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Use the SDK image to build the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase/"]
COPY ["WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories.csproj", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame"
RUN dotnet build "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.dll"]
```

Program.cs

````
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Serilog;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Business.ServicesImplementations;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Core.Abstractions;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Abstractions.Repositories;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.Data.Repositories;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase;
using WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame.DataBase.Entities;

namespace WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGame
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

                // Simplified: Only add essential services
                builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                    .CreateLogger();

                // Add services to the container.
                var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
                builder.Services.AddDbContext<WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireGameDbContext>(
                    optionBuilder => optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

                builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Question>, Repository<Question>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Answer>, Repository<Answer>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Game>, Repository<Game>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<GameQuestion>, Repository<GameQuestion>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Prize>, Repository<Prize>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<ColorPrize>, Repository<ColorPrize>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<LoginUser>, Repository<LoginUser>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Advertise>, Repository<Advertise>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<ClickedAd>, Repository<ClickedAd>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<GameTimer>, Repository<GameTimer>>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<SocialMediaLink>, Repository<SocialMediaLink>>();

                builder.Services.AddScoped<IQuestionService, QuestionService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IAnswerService, AnswerService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<ISourceService, JsonFileSourceService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IGameService, GameService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IPrizeService, PrizeService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IColorPrizeService, PrizeColorService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginUserService, LoginUserService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdvertiseService, AdvertiseService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IClickedAdService, ClickedAdService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<IGameTimer, GameTimerService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<ISocialMediaLinkService, SocialMediaLinkService>();

                builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
                builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
                builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                    options.Cookie.Name = ".Game.Session";
                    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                });

                builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/admin/Auth/Login");

                var app = builder.Build();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                        Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads")),
                    RequestPath = "/uploads"
                });
                // Simplified: Configure just the basic HTTP request pipeline
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseAuthentication();

                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseSession();
                app.UseMiddleware<PageLoadMiddleware>();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                        name: "AdminGame",
                        areaName: "AdminGame",
                        pattern: "admin/{controller=Auth}/{action=Login}/{id?}"
                    );

                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                });

                app.Run();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Basic error logging
                Console.WriteLine($"The application failed to start: {ex.Message};{ex.Data};{ex.InnerException};{ex.Source}");
            }
        }
        private static string GetPathToLogFile()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            sb.Append(@"\logs\");
            sb.Append($"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddhhmmss}");
            sb.Append("data.log");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
} ```
````